# How to show my name, but not my call back number when call out on Iphone 11

Tags: ios

I want to make calls so that people can see my name, but not have my cell number sent to avoid callbacks.

Comment: I do believe that is a function of the carrier you are using. You could call them and block caller ID but that may have side effects you don't want.

Comment: Incoming calls are recognised by their phone number over a regular "phone call" as opposed to Facetime etc. This is not solvable, it is how phone calls work.

Answer (score 1):

What does your cell phone carrier say when you ask them? The carrier is what determines this function, not Apple.